# Some overrided UITableView methods not being called after app relaunch

Tags: ios, objective-c

All my overrided UITableView methods are being called when I first run the program. But if I terminate the app in the simulator and re-launch from the simulator home screen, some of the overridden methods are not being called (ex. commitEditingStyle) and instead the preset method is called.

Is there a reason why they wouldn't be called after app relaunch but would work after a clear run?

My table code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // set toolbar delegate for editing toolbar style
    self.aToolbar.delegate = self;

    numberOfSections = 1; // for editing: initial number of sections

    // for testing
    NSLog(@"%@", ptrBookmarks1);

    // load bookmarks segment bar with user's most recent segment selections
    bookmarksSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = selectedBookmarksSegmentIndex;

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    //allow row selection during editing.
    //if the "Add New Song" row is selected we can trigger an insert.
    //rather than forcing the using to click the (+) icon directly
    self.aTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    // selected table data
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
    switch (bookmarksSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0: // Bookmarks 1 selected
            tableData = ptrBookmarks1;
            break;
        case 1: // Bookmarks 2 selected
            tableData = ptrBookmarks2;
            break;
        case 2: // My Songs selected
            tableData = ptrMySongs;
            break;
    }

    if ([self isEditing]) // the current view is in editing mode, return count + an extra row
        return [tableData count] + 1;
    else // return count
        return [tableData count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    // selected table data
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
    switch (bookmarksSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0: // Bookmarks 1 selected
            tableData = ptrBookmarks1;
            break;
        case 1: // Bookmarks 2 selected
            tableData = ptrBookmarks2;
            break;
        case 2: // My Songs selected
            tableData = ptrMySongs;
            break;
    }

    //if number of rows is greater than the total number of rows in the data set
    //and this view is in editing mode.
    //Initialize the cell for "Add New Song"
    //there will be an extra row once SetEditing: is called
    if(indexPath.row >= tableData.count && [self isEditing]){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Add New Song";
        //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator; // display arrow accessory
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone; // hide arrow accessory
    }
    return cell;

}


//VIEW CONTROLLER METHOD: IMPORTANT
//this is a method of the view controller
//if we use apple's editing button as follows:
//self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
//then this method will be called automatically for us.
//if we are using a button callback or similar method,
//then we need to call setEditing: manually on the view
-(void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{

    //wrap our code in an if statement
    //only run the code if we are not swipe deleting a row.
    //if we were called due to a swipeDelete action, ignore it
    if(isSwipeDeleting == NO){
        //call parent
        [aTableView setEditing:editing];
        [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];


        // selected table data
        NSMutableArray *tableData;
        switch (bookmarksSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0: // Bookmarks 1 selected
                tableData = ptrBookmarks1;
                break;
            case 1: // Bookmarks 2 selected
                tableData = ptrBookmarks2;
                break;
            case 2: // My Songs selected
                tableData = ptrMySongs;
                break;
        }


        //if editing mode
        if(editing){
            //batch the table view changes so that everything happens at once
            [self.aTableView beginUpdates];
            //for each section, insert a row at the end of the table
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++){
                //create an index path for the new row
                NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tableData.count inSection:i];
                //insert the NSIndexPath to create a new row. NOTE: this method takes an array of paths
                [self.aTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            }
            //animate the changes now
            [self.aTableView endUpdates];
        }else{
            //batch the table view changes so that everything happens at once
            [self.aTableView beginUpdates];
            //for each section, insert a row at the end of the table
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++){
                //create an index path for the new row
                NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tableData.count inSection:i];
                //insert the NSIndexPath to create a new row. NOTE: this method takes an array of paths
                [self.aTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            }
            //animate the changes now
            [self.aTableView endUpdates];
        }
    }
}


//DELEGATE METHOD:
//this method will be called for every row and allows us to set the
//editing syle icon(Delete,Insert)
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // selected table data
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
    switch (bookmarksSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0: // Bookmarks 1 selected
            tableData = ptrBookmarks1;
            break;
        case 1: // Bookmarks 2 selected
            tableData = ptrBookmarks2;
            break;
        case 2: // My Songs selected
            tableData = ptrMySongs;
            break;
    }

    // Detemine if it's in editing mode
    if (self.editing) {
        //use the + icon(add icon) on row
        //if this is the additional row created in setEditing:animated:
        if(indexPath.row >= tableData.count){
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
        }
        else {
            //use the delete icon on this row
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
        }
    }
    else
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}


//handle the deletion/insertion
//this method is called when the delete or insert icon has been press.
//we should update our dataSource by inserting or removing the selected INDEX
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // selected table data
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
    switch (bookmarksSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0: // Bookmarks 1 selected
            tableData = ptrBookmarks1;
            break;
        case 1: // Bookmarks 2 selected
            tableData = ptrBookmarks2;
            break;
        case 2: // My Songs selected
            tableData = ptrMySongs;
            break;
    }

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) { // the delete icon was clicked
        // delete pre-test
        NSLog(@"Array before delete: %@", tableData);
        NSLog(@"Directory before delete: ");
        [self readDirectoryContents];

        // if deleting a song or its pages that's in view, switch view to previous MySong if exists, otherwise About page/a blank page
        ////////insert code here////////

        // remove file and its annotations from directory (if deleting from My Songs)
        if (tableData == ptrMySongs) {
            [self deleteImportedSongsheet:tableData[indexPath.row]];

        }

        //remove row from tableData
        [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //remove the row in the tableView
        [self.aTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];


        // delete post-test
        NSLog(@"Array after delete: %@", tableData);
        NSLog(@"Directory after delete: ");
        [self readDirectoryContents];

        [self.aTableView reloadData];
    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) { // the insert icon was clicked
        /*
        //add a new row to the datasource
        [tableData addObject:@"New Icon"];
        //insert a row in the tableView because the plusIcon was clicked.
        [self.aTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];*/

        self.editing = false; // turn off editing

        // ---SEGUE TO SONG IMPORT OPTIONS TABLE---
        SongImportView *songImportView =
            [[SongImportView alloc]
             initWithNibName:@"SongImportView" bundle:nil];

        // forward the My Songs array
        songImportView.ptrMySongs = ptrMySongs;

        // set delegate
        songImportView.delegate = self;

        // push SongImportView
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:songImportView animated:YES];

        [SongImportView release];
    }
}

//if we are in editing mode we do not want to perform Seque Transition
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"MyDetailView"] && [self isEditing]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}


//this method is called when the user swipes to delete a row.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    isSwipeDeleting = YES;//user just swipe to delete a row
}
//when the user cancel the swipe or click the delete button
//this method is call
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    isSwipeDeleting = NO;//swipe to delete ended. No longer showing the DELETE button in cell
}

// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return NO;
    //return YES;
}

// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {

    // MUST CHANGE canMoveRowAtIndexPath TO ENABLE THIS

    NSString *item;

    // selected table data
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
    switch (bookmarksSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0: // Bookmarks 1 selected
            tableData = ptrBookmarks1;
            break;
        case 1: // Bookmarks 2 selected
            tableData = ptrBookmarks2;
            break;
        case 2: // My Songs selected
            tableData = ptrMySongs;
            break;
    }

    item = [[tableData objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row] retain];
    [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [tableData insertObject:item atIndex:toIndexPath.row];

    [item release];
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

//DELEGATE METHOD:
//the user selected a row
//In order for the user to perform an INSERTION action on a row,
//they have to click the + icon icon. We can implement this method
//so that they can click anywhere on the "Add New Song" to add a new row
//tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES; must be set
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //deselect the selected row with animatiion
    [self.aTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    // selected table data
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
    switch (bookmarksSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0: // Bookmarks 1 selected
            tableData = ptrBookmarks1;
            break;
        case 1: // Bookmarks 2 selected
            tableData = ptrBookmarks2;
            break;
        case 2: // My Songs selected
            tableData = ptrMySongs;
            break;
    }

    //if the selected  row was the "Add New Song" row call tableView:commitEditingStyle:
    //to add a new row
    if (indexPath.row >= tableData.count && [self isEditing]) {
        [self tableView:tableView commitEditingStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else { // otherwise do regular table item selection
        [self.delegate didTapBookmarksTable:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

}


// to scroll the table to the top row that was last viewed
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    NSIndexPath *iP;

    switch (bookmarksSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0: // Bookmarks 1 selected
            if ([ptrBookmarks1 count] > 0) { // make sure that there is something in the table before scrolling to it, otherwise will crash

                iP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:bookmark1listPositionRow inSection:bookmark1listPositionSection];
                [aTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:iP atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
            }
            break;
        case 1: // Bookmarks 2 selected
            if ([ptrBookmarks2 count] > 0) { // make sure that there is something in the table before scrolling to it, otherwise will crash

                iP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:bookmark2listPositionRow inSection:bookmark2listPositionSection];
                [aTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:iP atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
            }
            break;
        case 2: // My Songs selected
            if ([ptrMySongs count] > 0) { // make sure that there is something in the table before scrolling to it, otherwise will crash

                iP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:mysongslistPositionRow inSection:mysongslistPositionSection];
                [aTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:iP atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
            }
            break;
    }


}

// remember the top row that was last viewed
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    NSIndexPath *ip;

    switch (bookmarksSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0: // Bookmarks 1 selected
            if ([ptrBookmarks1 count] > 0) { // make sure that there is something in the table before scrolling to it, otherwise will crash
                ip = [[aTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] objectAtIndex:0];
                bookmark1listPositionSection = ip.section;
                bookmark1listPositionRow = ip.row;
            }
            break;
        case 1: // Bookmarks 2 selected
            if ([ptrBookmarks2 count] > 0) { // make sure that there is something in the table before scrolling to it, otherwise will crash
                ip = [[aTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] objectAtIndex:0];
                bookmark2listPositionSection = ip.section;
                bookmark2listPositionRow = ip.row;
            }
            break;
        case 2: // My Songs selected
            if ([ptrMySongs count] > 0) { // make sure that there is something in the table before scrolling to it, otherwise will crash
                ip = [[aTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] objectAtIndex:0];
                mysongslistPositionSection = ip.section;
                mysongslistPositionRow = ip.row;
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: This code doesn't show where you're assigning the delegate. Are other delegate methods getting called appropriately?

Comment: Are you sure the methods aren't getting called? Or are you just going by the logs? You won't see the logs in the xcode debugger if you launch an app directly from the simulator, as it is not actually hooked up to the debugger.

Comment: @JakeT. I don't think that I'm assigning any delegates outside of the code I posted. I followed a tutorial to implement these methods, so I'm not too sure about delegates.

Comment: *"My NSLogs don't show up (or is that part of the debugger you mention?)"* yes, that's what @JakeT meant by the debugger. You will only see NSLog output if you have Xcode *connected to* the running instance of the app. Launching the app by tapping the icon in the simulator does *not* attach it to the Xcode debugger.

Comment: @Dima You're right, it was just my debugger not displaying logs. Thank you so much.

Comment: Those logs are stored on the device. Say you build the app to your phone, then you're not running through xcode, but want to get log info, you can do that through Window > Devices. This does not include simulator devices. They show up on the list but don't have log options. These may be stored elsewhere, but I am unaware.